# How to append query parameter at runtime using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Through JavaScript I am appending one query parameter to the page url and I am facing one strange behaiviour.

```
<div>
    <a href="Default3.aspx?id=2">Click me</a>
</div>


$(function () {
    window.location.href = window.location.href + "&q=" + "aa";
});
```

Now I am appending `&q=aa` in default3.aspx and in this page the `&q=aa` is getting added continuously, causing the URL to become:

```
 http://localhost:1112/WebSite2/Default3.aspx?id=2&q=aa&q=aa&q=aa&q=aa&q=aa&q=aa&q=aa&q=aa&q=aa&q=aa&q=aa&q=aa&q=aa&q=aa&q=aa&q=aa&q=aa&q=aa&q=aa&q=aa&q=aa
```

One would say just pass it like `<a href="Default3.aspx?id=2&q=aa">Click me</a>`, but I cant do that. The value of this query parameter is actually the value of an HTML element which is in default3.aspx. I have to add it in runtime.

What are the ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason this happens is because if you change the `window.location` value the browser will perform a redirect to the new location and as you are doing this in the `document.ready` this happens indefinitely.

Before doing this redirect you might want to check if the current url already contains these parameters.

```
$(function () {
    var suffix = '&q=aa';
    var currentUrl = window.location.href;
    if (currentUrl.match(suffix + '$') != suffix) {
        window.location.href = window.location.href + suffix;
    }
});
```

Remark: Using javascript for this purpose seems to me like a bad idea. I would perform this redirect on the server side which would be more reliable. In your default.aspx page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    var q = Request["q"];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(q))
    {
        // q parameter has not been set => redirect
        Response.Redirect("/default.aspx?q=aa");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Darin - can u pls explain if (currentUrl.match(suffix + '$') != suffix) {  i mean why the $ sign ? Thanks for all ur help

Comment: @Wondering: The `$` is used in regular expressions to signify the end of a string. Thus `&q=aa$` will match only at the end of the URL.

Comment: I'd probably use `if(/&q=aa$/.test(currentUrl)) {` instead though.

Comment: @Darin -True.very true.The flow.architecture is totally wrong, actually this is enhancement, so cant help it. Thanks.